# Detect whether running on HiDPI display

Tags: java, macos, swt, retina-display

How to detect from an SWT application that it is running on a HiDPI ("retina") display?

Answer (score 0):

The class `Device`, which is a superclass of `Display`, has a method called `getDPI()` which will return the DPI value of the display:

```
Device device = shell.getDisplay();
System.out.println(device.getDPI());
```

Comment: I know, but how to detect whether OS X running in "retina" display mode?

Comment: Well, what else do you need to know in addition to the DPI setting? I don't know much about OSX, but since SWT has (almost) the same API for each platform, my guess would be, that you can't get that information from SWT. You might be able to run something in the command line from SWT and parse the result though...

Comment: For the "retina/HiDPI" mode on OS X one virtual pixel maps to 2x2 physical pixels (e.g. 1920x1200 monitor runs with a 960x600 HiDPI resolution). This results in very smooth drawings.